# Occasional problems with Filezilla FTP login in IIBv9

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I have got an IIBv9 application which outputs files to a Filezilla FTP server using the standard FileOutput node and an FTP security identity. In most cases, it works perfectly. However, it occasionally fails to transfer a file producing an exception:

```
          (0x03000000:NameValue):File     = 'AbstractFileOutputNode.java' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Line     = 809 (INTEGER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Function = 'transferToFtpServer' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Type     = '' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Name     = '' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Label    = '' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Catalog  = 'BIPmsgs' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Severity = 3 (INTEGER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Number   = 3381 (INTEGER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Text     = '' (CHARACTER)
          (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert   = (
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = 'FileOutput' (CHARACTER)
          )
          (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert   = (
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = '(myFlowName)' (CHARACTER)
          )
          (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert   = (
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = '(host)' (CHARACTER)
          )
          (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert   = (
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = '(login)' (CHARACTER)
          )
          (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert   = (
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = 'USER =>response:  ReplyCode: 220' (CHARACTER)
          )
          (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert   = (
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
            (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = 'FTP' (CHARACTER)
```

Filezilla logs only have the following lines:

```
(005433) 21.12.2020 7:42:29 - (not logged in) (192.168.15.104)> 220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
(005433) 21.12.2020 7:42:35 - (not logged in) (192.168.15.104)> USER (login)
(005433) 21.12.2020 7:42:35 - (not logged in) (192.168.15.104)> 331 Password required for (login)
(005433) 21.12.2020 7:42:35 - (not logged in) (192.168.15.104)> disconnected.
```

The broker restart or the filezilla server restart seem to help overcome the issue, and the same file is transferred successfully. But I cannot understand what causes the troubles.

Comment: It seems like there was a disconnection, so the server expected a user login, but the client didn't understand the demand. I suggest testing the client's router for termination of the client's DHCP lease, and the same for the ISP. It might be that the IP address of the client has changed, causing disconnection.

Comment: @harrymc, seems plausible because the restart helps. The IP address is static and does not change. But there may be network troubles. I'll accept your answer if you post it:)

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the log is that there was a disconnection.
The client re-connected, but the server expected a user login.
The client didn't understand the demand and wanted to continue with upload.
The result was that the upload just stopped.

One common reason for such an interruption is if the IP address of the client has
changed. This can happen if the client's DHCP lease on the router has elapsed,
and the same can happen for the ISP.
But many other reasons are possible, too many to list.

The explanation of a momentary disconnection is supported by the poster's experience:
"The broker restart or the filezilla server restart seem to help overcome the issue,
and the same file is transferred successfully".